# One shared vendor with two projects

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, autoload, vendor

I'm working on 2 applications right now. The first one is a CMS, and the second is a shop. I want to move my vendor one level above and the share it between projects.

So my structure will be something like this:

```
project1/
project2/
shared_vendor/
```

I read about this.
I have changed the `app/autoload.php` loader variable from:

```
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

to:

```
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';
```

And I have also changed `vendor-dir` in my `composer.json` from:

```
    "config": {
      "bin-dir": "bin",
      "vendor-dir": "vendor"
    },
```

to:

```
    "config": {
      "bin-dir": "bin",
      "vendor-dir": "/../vendor"
    },
```

And after this I'm getting this error:

```
ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 20: Attempted to load 
class "CmsUserBundle" from namespace "Cms\UserBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I forget to change something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the CmsUserBundle live in `project_1/src/` or in `shared_vendor/`?

Comment: You are missing to manually edit composer autoload configuration which loads the project namespaces.

Comment: Why is it that you want to do this? Having 2 separate systems using the same vendors means that you have to keep both package dependencies to the same versions.

Comment: @WouterJ Yes, CmsUserBundle is in project1/src.

Comment: @code-jaff, what should I precisely change in composer?

Comment: @Qoop I want to have the same vendor for all my apps. I think about making vendor all-in-one library package. And that doesn't mean that all projects use all libs. Is that not good attitude?

Comment: My only issue is that it means that each of your apps are tied to the same version of packages. This would mean that every time you wanted to update a package (which may also update any number of other packages in the directory) you would have to make sure that every one of your apps was not broken by the changes. I just imagine that trying to keep all of your apps dependencies in sync would be far more trouble than it would be a benefit.

Comment: Shared libraries used to be a standard.  It didn't end well.  On the other hand, fixing this problem will give you insight in how the autoload process works.  You need to fix your psr-0 or 4 section in the composer.json file.  But once you get it working then you should probably abandon this approach.

Comment: That's a really bad idea!

Comment: Ok, maybe that's a bad idea. But I want to do this, test it and then decide or this solution is bad for me too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Composer works on a per project basis.

One project - one vendor folder. Not, two projects and one "shared" vendor folder.

We had the "shared" vendor folder approach with PEAR long enough and it simply didn't work out. Managing different project requirements with a global vendor folder is a pain, because every project has different requirements.

Anyway...

if you like the "shared vendor folder" setup, i would suggest to create something like a "wrapper" or "super" project, which acts as container repository for the two other projects. The wrapper project will contain the `composer.json` file with the requirements for both(!) projects. That means that you are working against the same set of dependencies in both sub-projects.

This allows to define requirements for both sub-projects (cms and shop)
in the "wrapper" repo. Basically, i'm suggesting the following structure:

```
|-container-project
  +-CMS
    |-src
    +-tests
  +-Shop
    |-src
    +-tests
  +-vendors      // contains dependencies for both projects (CMS + Shop)
|-composer.json  // define requirements for both projects
```

This setup allows to introduce `composer.json` files for the subprojects, too.
You just have to transfer the requirements from the `composer.json` file of the super-project to the `composer.json` file of a subproject.

Now, it's also possible to tweak the autoloading behavior of the sub-projects by registering autoloaders in a specific order.

Comment: Ok, thx for explanation. I will use one vendor for one project, as you all wrote. :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements and if the only thing you need/want to share between your multiple projects is the vendor directory, you could just create symlinks in each project except whatever the main one which already has the the vendor directory.

For example:

```
cd /var/www/SiteA
composer install
# git clone new project into /var/www/SiteB
cd ../SiteB
# If vendor directory is already there, delete it: rm -rf vendor
# create symlink to Site A's vendor directory
ln -s /var/www/SiteA/vendor
```

Unless you know for sure that all projects are definitely going to need exactly the same versions of your dependancies, this maybe not a good plan.

Answer (score 1):

**For Laravel 5, 6 and 7+**

After adding the new vendor folder config:

```
...
"config": {
    ...,
    "vendor-dir": "../vendor"
},
...
```

Then run `composer update`

Then you need to change two files:

1. For your app: `public/index.php`

   `require __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';`
2. Your artisan command in the root folder: `artisan`

   `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`
3. Package auto-discovery in `Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest`:

   `$this->vendorPath = $basePath.'/../vendor'; //Change this line in constructor`

and rerun

```
php artisan package:discover --ansi
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I run into the same problem. I'm using Laravel 7 and I solved the problem with the following method.
I wrote a shellscript (my-vendor.sh) at the root of my project with the following code :

```
 #!/bin/bash

MY_VENDOR_DIRECTORY=my-vendor
VENDOR_DIRECTORY=vendor

if [ ! -d "$MY_VENDOR_DIRECTORY" ]
then
  echo "Le dossier $MY_VENDOR_DIRECTORY n'existe pas : on le crée."
  mkdir "$MY_VENDOR_DIRECTORY"
else
  echo "Le dossier $MY_VENDOR_DIRECTORY existe : on le vide."
  rm -rf "$MY_VENDOR_DIRECTORY/*"
fi

echo "Copie des fichiers autoload généré depuis $VENDOR_DIRECTORY vers $MY_VENDOR_DIRECTORY."
cp "$VENDOR_DIRECTORY/autoload.php" "$MY_VENDOR_DIRECTORY"
cp -R "$VENDOR_DIRECTORY/composer" "$MY_VENDOR_DIRECTORY"

cd "$MY_VENDOR_DIRECTORY/composer"

echo "Remplacement de 'require \$file' par \str_replace(\"$MY_VENDOR_DIRECTORY\/composer\/..\", \"vendor\", \$file)"
sed -i "s/require \$file/require \\str_replace('$MY_VENDOR_DIRECTORY\/composer\/..', 'vendor', \$file)/" autoload_real.php

echo "Remplacement de 'include \$file' par \str_replace(\"$MY_VENDOR_DIRECTORY\/composer\/..\", \"vendor\", \$file) "
sed -i "s/include \$file/require \\str_replace('$MY_VENDOR_DIRECTORY\/composer\/..', 'vendor', \$file)/" ClassLoader.php
```

Then, I replace the following code in `public/index.php` :

- `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'` => by `require __DIR__.'/../my-vendor/autoload.php';`

After that, I add `my-vendor.sh` command in the `post-autoload-dump` scripts.

I made this modifications in my two projects, launch `composer dump-autoload` and it work like a charm :)

A link to the gist : https://gist.github.com/flibidi67/7c2cfdc1ff1b977b48204be0bee5eb76

Hope this can help someone else ;)