# How to deal with composers disk space usage when have many projects?

Tags: php, composer-php, diskspace

I know that has been discussed already ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30000063/57091) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32166453/57091)). But I still don't know how to deal with the problem: On my server (Linux) I have many different PHP sites hosted (50+). In conjunction with composer (1.9) it takes a lot of disk space because of the respective vendor folders.

I think I understand that composer is [project based](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#dependency-management) and that there can be only one version of a package in a single project. Anyway, many packages exists redundant on the machine's file system. Especially, if a PHP framework gets used in different projects, many packages exists more than once.

I want to reduce the amount of disk space somehow. Is there any reasonable or even official way to re-use packages on a machine?

btw: I install the packages with [`--no-dev`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install-i) option. I know I can disable the composer cache with [`--no-cache`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global-options). This can save some space.

Comment: Personal opinion: Renting some GBs more space is just a handful of dollars (or so), compared to building a custom solution that might change Composer's core logic, which will take you hours and weeks of stress and exotic errors. Take the easy route :)

Comment: Has anyone experience with [letudiant/composer-shared-package-plugin](https://packagist.org/packages/letudiant/composer-shared-package-plugin)?

Comment: @Sliq I considered that already - without a real conclusion. It is an option of course. But: Managing redundant packages causes also more traffic and takes more time. Also, more backup disk space is required with more data. And so on... I'm wondering why there is not package repository for the whole machine, and just symlinks in the vendor folders.

Comment: That solution would be problematic, because it's easy to add new versions, but hard to remove old versions. Such an operation would require to always know about all installed software and the exact package versions required. Effectively you'd create something like an PHP application server that requires a specific installation process for every application. If somebody thinks this is a necessary solution for a common problem, then they will write software for it. Until then, everyone else is simply adding more harddrives.

Comment: @Sven That's understandable. It goes beyond this question, but I could imagine that [hard links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) would solve this problem easily.

Comment: Or you can use some copy-on-write filesystem such as BTRFS and run [rmlint](https://github.com/sahib/rmlint) from time to time to deduplicate data. And `/vendor` is not a thing that should be backed up, because you always can restore it with `composer.lock`